# C++: Accessing data of dynamic structures within extern function

Tags: c++, matlab, dynamic, struct, mex

I have a problem with passing dynamically allocated structures to a function and accessing it's content.

The program uses mex to pass data from Matlab to C++. I use Visual Studio.

The structure I define in a header in 'InOut.h'

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>

struct sObjects {
    std::string Type;
    float *Position;
};
typedef struct sObject sObject;
```

In the main function I than allocate the structure is in 'MainFcn_Mex.cpp'

```
#include "MainFcn_Mex.h"

// ...

// get number of Objects from Matlab
int N_Obj = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]);

sObjects *Objects = new sObjects[N_Obj]; 

for (int k=0; k<N_Obj; k++)  {

    // get the pointer pointer map
    pMap = mxGetField(prhs[1],k,"Type");
    Objects[k].Type = mxArrayToString(pMap);

    // get the pointer pointer map
    pMap = mxGetField(prhs[1],k,"Position");
    // setting pointer to the first Element
    Objects[k].Position = (float*)mxGetPr(pMap);

    mexPrintf("Objects(%d,1).Type:  %s \n", k+1, Objects[k].Type);
}

create_Objects(Objects, N_Obj);
```

The function create_Objects is in a differente file 'create_Objects.cpp' and included via 'MainFcn_Mex.h':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <direct.h>
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "math.h"
#include <cmath>

#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"

#include <cuda.h>  
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include "InOut.h"

void create_Objects(sObjects *Objects, int N_Obj);
```

The content of 'create_Objects.cpp' so far is:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include "math.h"
#include <cmath>
#include "InOut.h"
#include "mex.h"

void create_Objects(sObjects *Objects, int N_Obj)
{
    for (int k=0; k<N_Obj; k++)  {
        mexPrintf("Objects(%d,1).Type:  %s \n", k+1, Objects[k].Type);
    }
}
```

Visual Studio tells me:

> "error C2676: binary '[' : 'sObjects' does not define this operator or
>   a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator"

Why can I access the data in the main function and not in seccondary functions?

How can I access a dynamically allocated structure in other functions, when its size isn't known at compile time?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: you're showing us only pieces of the code; for one, where do you have `Objects` defined? Also are `create_Objects` and `create_OpticsObjects` the same? please provide complete information, preferably with a minimal working code.. Currently the question is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed things up reducing the code to the parts I thought they might be crucial ... I edited the orignal post above

Comment: I found a compilable working solution which I don't understand. I´ll try to summarize: I created the structure like `sObjects *Objects = new sObjects[N_Obj];` ... with a pointer ... then I allocate the structure within the loop. It works if I pass Objects like `create_Objects(sObjects *Objects, int N_Obj);`. But it doesn't if I pass it via a reference &

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the problem here. Please post the code you're *actually* using along with the exact error message...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use `struct` directly as a `typedef`.  Simply add `typedef` to your `struct` definition, will turn it into a type.

Like this:

```
... #include "mex.h"

typedef struct sObjects {
    std::string Type;
    float *Position;
};
```

(Otherwise you should use the full `struct` keyword as in `void create_OpticsObjects(struct sObjects &Objects, int N_Obj)`.)

Your function prototypes don't need the `extern` qualifier.

You don't need `extern` unless you want globals variables. You seem to want simply global `struct`s or types in your example, so `extern` is not required.

**Using extern for globals**

What you could be referring to is an instance of your object (or a pointer to your object), and that can be made global by using `extern`. as in this excerpt from the header file:

```
... #include "mex.h"

typedef struct sObjects {
    std::string Type;
    float *Position;
};

extern sObjects *pointerToOnesObjects;
```

Then in ONE source file, you need to declare the 'real' variable as in (this is good to initialise it here):

```
sObjects *pointerToOnesObjects = NULL;
```

With this method your variable `pointerToOnesObjects`  is now available globally (in all your source files that use the same header file).

Comment: Hope it has helped.  Please mark the 'answer' accordingly :).

Comment: sorry, I was to fast ... I got rid of the extern and I defined the structure with typdef 'struct sObjects { ...}; typedef struct sObject sObject;' but the error "error C2676: binary '[' : 'sObjects' does not define this operator" maintains ... I also tried passing it directly as 'void create_OpticsObjects(struct sObjects &Objects, int N_Obj);'

Comment: Once you have used ´typedef struct´ AAAA, AAAA can be used by itself as it is now a 'type'.  You will not need to use the struct keyword either in 'void create_OpticsObjects(struct sObjects &Objects, int N_Obj);' ...

Comment: @Grantly: the OP is using C++, in which case the `typedef` of `struct` is not necessary (unlike in C): http://stackoverflow.com/q/612328/97160

Comment: Thanks @Amro, you are right.  However it can be good practice, to avoid confusion in some weird cases.

Comment: @Grantly: IMO there is no confusion. You do the same when you specify C++ classes instead of structs, you don't prefix the type name with anything..